# Why is Python not using the working directory and how to fix it?

Tags: python, linux, import, python-import

I have a problem, which takes rather long to explain, so I'm gonna break it down to the interesting parts. I try to parse some kconfigs with the kconfiglib.py. Here is my code (of `config.in`)

```
[intro_code]
source "b.in"
```

My code is exactly doing what it should at [intro_code]. I'm not sure sure if `source` is a python-keyword, but it's about entering/including a different file (here with the name `b.in`, located in the same folder as the executed script)

**The error message:** Now when running the script, the following error message appears:

```
IOError: config.in:51: sourced file "b.in" (expands to
"b.in") not found. Perhaps base_dir
(argument to Config.__init__(), currently
"$srctree") is set to the wrong value.
```

**What i did to solve:** I tried to change the working directory to `Sourcecodes` (that's where `config.in` and `b.in` are located) on  top of the `config.in`:

```
os.chdir("/home/fedor/Sourcecodes") 
retval = os.getcwd()
print "Directory changed successfully %s" % retval
```

during execution it returns:

> Directory changed successfully /home/fedor/Sourcecodes

So the directory seems to be alright, but the same error message appears anyways.

**It is working when**: using the absolute path to `b.in` (like `source "/home/fedor/Sourcecodes/b.in")` then it's working, but that's not how I could use the script.

Does anybody know how to tell python to look in the same directory as the executed script ?

[Edit:] as wished, the full code:

I call `python /home/fedor/Sourcecodes/Kconfiglib/examples/print_tree.py /home/fedor/Sourcecodes/config.in`

the `print_tree.py` from kconfiglib-examples:

```
# Prints a tree of all items in the configuration

import kconfiglib
import sys
import os

os.chdir("/home/fedor/BR1311") 


retval = os.getcwd()

print "Directory changed successfully %s" % retval

def print_with_indent(s, indent):
    print (" " * indent) + s

def print_items(items, indent):
    for item in items:
        if item.is_symbol():
            print_with_indent("config {0}".format(item.get_name()), indent)
        elif item.is_menu():
            print_with_indent('menu "{0}"'.format(item.get_title()), indent)
            print_items(item.get_items(), indent + 2)
        elif item.is_choice():
            print_with_indent('choice', indent)
            print_items(item.get_items(), indent + 2)
        elif item.is_comment():
            print_with_indent('comment "{0}"'.format(item.get_text()), indent)

conf = kconfiglib.Config(sys.argv[1])
print_items(conf.get_top_level_items(), 0)
```

---

the `config.in`

```
menu "Audio and video applications"
config BR2_PACKAGE_WIPE
    bool "wipe"
    help
      Wipe is a little command for securely erasing files
      from magnetic media. It compiles under various unix platforms.

      http://wipe.sourceforge.net

config BR2_PACKAGE_BONNIE
    bool "bonnie++"
    depends on BR2_INSTALL_LIBSTDCPP
    depends on BR2_USE_MMU # fork()
    help
      Filesystem tester

      http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/

comment "bonnie++ needs a toolchain w/ C++"
    depends on BR2_USE_MMU
    depends on !BR2_INSTALL_LIBSTDCPP
endmenu

source "b.in"
```

---

and the `b.in` (which is exactly the same as `config.in` but of the missing `source` command in the end):

```
menu "Audio and video applications"
config BR2_PACKAGE_WIPE
    bool "wipe"
    help
      Wipe is a little command for securely erasing files
      from magnetic media. It compiles under various unix platforms.

      http://wipe.sourceforge.net

config BR2_PACKAGE_BONNIE
    bool "bonnie++"
    depends on BR2_INSTALL_LIBSTDCPP
    depends on BR2_USE_MMU # fork()
    help
      Filesystem tester

      http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/

comment "bonnie++ needs a toolchain w/ C++"
    depends on BR2_USE_MMU
    depends on !BR2_INSTALL_LIBSTDCPP
endmenu
```

Comment: Post the full code, please.

Comment: This depends entirely on what `kconfiglib.py` **does**. It appears to have a base directory argument you have ignored.

Comment: I added the code at the end of my top post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right in the error message you posted:

```
Perhaps base_dir (argument to Config.__init__(), currently "$srctree") 
is set to the wrong value.
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/ulfalizer/Kconfiglib/blob/master/kconfiglib.py) on github, the `__init__` for the `Config` class takes multiple parameters, all with defaults.

```
def __init__(self,
             filename = "Kconfig",
             base_dir = "$srctree",
             print_warnings = True,
             print_undef_assign = False):
```

...and in the docstring for the class, the `base_dir` parameter is explained:

```
base_dir (default: "$srctree") -- The base directory relative to which
'source' statements within Kconfig files will work. For the
Linux kernel this should be the top-level directory of the
kernel tree. $-references to environment variables will be
expanded.

The environment variable 'srctree' is set by the Linux makefiles
to the top-level kernel directory. A default of "." would not
work if an alternative build directory is used.
```

I suspect that if you pass in `'/home/fedor/BR1311'` to this `__init__` instead of changing to it, like:

```
conf = kconfiglib.Config(sys.argv[1], '/home/fedor/BR1311')
```

things will work much better.

Comment: Fantastic :) that's the solution: `conf = kconfiglib.Config(sys.argv[1], '/home/fedor/BR1311')` Thanks very much for that precise answer